# Difference between logs, timber, and lumber

Tags: meaning, differences, vocabulary

I'm interested in the distinctions between these three terms. Here's what I already know: timber is wood that is still attached to the ground, and still has its bark on. Lumber is already felled, and no longer has its bark. [[source]](http://www.differencebetween.net/object/difference-between-lumber-and-timber/)

But my question is, does lumber refer to wood that is already processed into boards and planks? Or does it refer to felled wood that has not yet been processed into boards and planks?

Comment: What about the summary included in the article you link still has you wondering about these terms?

Comment: It wasn't clear whether lumber implies that the wood is already sawn into boards and planks.

Comment: From the Summary: "3. *Timber* is the word used to refer to wooden boards in the U.K. and Australia while *lumber* is the wooden board for the American and Canadian denomination."

Comment: Neither word comes up particularly commonly in my normal, day-to-day conversations, but when on occasion I do use _timber_, I would say it’s almost never in reference to wood that’s still attached to the ground. I call that _trees_. The immediate mental image that _timber_ conjures up for me is (more or less) unprocessed tree trunks being transported on boats or lorries (or rafts, but I’ll admit that’s probably just my romanticising mind going into Canadian lumberjack overdrive), or drying in huge piles by the side of the road.

Comment: For me, *timber* usually collocates with *stands of t.* and so I can readily see how it could mean uncut trees.  Being an American, *lumber* is what I buy at the lumber yard to build things out of. And Logs are felled tree trunks stripped of branches but with the bark still on. But I have seen *timber* used to mean dimensioned lumber especially when it is really big pieces like for the main beams for a building, etc.

Comment: @Jim Interesting. If you type "lumber yard" into Google Images you see both cases: (1) logs and (2) boards and planks.

Comment: Yes, this is is more confirmation that the terms are used differently in different parts of the world and may also be used interchangeably by some people. There is no one right answer. Here's [wikipedia's treatise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lumber_yard): "*Lumber yards sell products made at lumber mills [...] Generally, timber yards are locations where raw logs and other wood or forest products are processed and stored. The terms "lumber yard" and "timber yard" are sometimes used interchangeably, and timber yards may include additional aspects that lumber yards encompass, and vice versa.

Comment: An interesting etymological link: 'timber' is a close cousin to German 'Zimmer', and Bob Zimmerman's hero is *Woody* Guthrie.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It might make more sense to pull up a few definitions for these nouns:

> **Log**:
>
> - "1. A rough bulky piece of timber unhewed; a block; a piece of wood." (Lloyd's Encyclopædic dictionary, Vol. 4, 1895, page 626, "lœwigite—loganite")
> - "1. A section of the trunk or of a large branch of a felled tree, either in its natural state or cut up for use in building, as firewood, etc." (Webster's New World College Dictionary, as provided by the Associated Press Stylebook Online, 2015-04-14)
>
> **Lumber**:
>
> - "7. Marketable Timber." (Lloyd's Encyclopædic dictionary, Vol. 4, 1895, page 668, "lumbaginous—lump")
> - "2. Timber sawed into beams, planks, boards, etc. of sizes convenient for building or carpentry." (Webster's New World College Dictionary, as provided by the Associated Press Stylebook Online, 2015-04-14)
>
> **Timber**:
>
> - "Trees cut down, squared, or capable of being squared, into beams, rafters, boards, planks, etc., to be employed in the construction of houses, ships, etc., or in carpentry, joinery, etc." (The American Encyclopædic Dictionary, Vol. 4, 1896, page 4096, "tilly—timber")
> - "2. Wood suitable for building houses, ships, etc., whether cut or still in the form of trees." (Webster's New World College Dictionary, as provided by the Associated Press Stylebook Online, 2015-04-14)

So what we can get from these definitions is that *timber* is the tree or trees that were planted in a grove for the purpose of cutting or found in a forest, which, when cut down, could then further be cut up into various useful pieces of wood that could then be used in building various projects, such as houses or ships.

[image: Timber waiting to be turned into Lumber. Source: Wikipedia/Ian Mitchell]
[Image source.](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Felled_timber_waiting_uplift_-_Garbat_Forest_-_geograph.org.uk_-_1369495.jpg)

*Lumber* is the wood, already cut to any marketable size — from boards meant for flooring, to rafters and beams meant for holding up a structure. If you went to a Home Depot, or another large home-improvement store, you would usually buy the marketable bits of wood here in the lumber department.

[image: Marketable Timber. Planks, Boards, etc. Source: Blogspot/John Pluta]
[Image source.](http://augustageorgian.blogspot.com/2013/12/the-home-depot-home-depot-augusta.html)

*Logs* are the piece of a felled tree, usually the size of a large branch (could even be a large branch) up to a whole section of a trunk, and generally just a rough piece of wood that you could use either as-is (such as in building a log cabin), for use in small-to-medium projects, or to be used as firewood. Not generally to be found in a finished and marketable form such as a board or plank, which would be lumber. However logs can be marketed and sold as logs, just not as lumber.

[image: A pile of Logs. Source: TreeScapersDirectory.com]
[Image source.](http://www.treescapersdirectory.com/)

Comment: Really great answer! I'm sorry that after all this time I haven't upvoted or accepted it. That has just been remedied.

Answer (score 1):

When you have a tree that is standing in nature, unharmed, its called timber.

When they cut down the tree, they also remove the branches from it. The tree as it is now is called lumber. A lumber is basically a long tree without its roots and all branches removed. Usually it still has the barks on.

In this form, it can be moved to a facility for processing.

Comment: The article I mentioned says that lumber can immediately be used for construction or furniture. This seems to imply that lumber is already processed (sawn into boards and planks). I'm curious to know which definition is correct... and if you have a source to back yours up.

Comment: My source is an explaination from a lumberjack on Discovery Channel. Nothing unfortunately that I can link to. I guess this becomes a matter of opinion.

Comment: 1. Lumber is uncountable; "a lumber" is not something a native speaker would ever emit. Ditto for "bark": "barks" is the second person singular form of the verb, not a plural noun, because the noun form doesn't have a plural. 2. If you have a tree standing in nature, unharmed, it's called a... tree, oddly enough. "Timber" is what you yell when the tree you just cut down is in the act of falling.